# Encrypt User last name in wordpress for security reasons

Tags: customization, security, user-registration

Can Anyone help me to encrypt only the user's last name in WordPress? I only want to encrypt user's last name in the database for some security reasons. I am unable to find the solution Please let me with this

Comment: what are the specific security concerns behind this? Answering the question as is would mean there would be no way to discover the last name of a user making storing it in the first place pointless, especially when a user can put their last name in the nickname or display user as fields to bypass this. Is this for compliance with specific security policies? Note that there are different kinds of encryption, e.g. hashing etc, you'll need to be more specific about why you want this and the expectations or you might end up with something that hurts security or isn't usable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically I am working on medical site and there is most confidential data that's why I want to encrypt user last name as well